# How to Union element in array if each element of array is a function?

Tags: typescript

```
export type MakeActionType = (name: string) => {[key: string]: string}
const combineActionType = <AT extends (MakeActionType | undefined)[]>(...actionTypeList: AT) => (name: string) => {
    return actionTypeList.reduce(
        (previous, makeActionType) => {
            const actionType = makeActionType ? makeActionType(name) : {}
            return {
                ...previous,
                ...actionType,
            }
        },
        {}
    )
}
```

Now I applied the function above like this:

```
const abAction = combineActionType((name) => ({a: 'a'}), (name) => ({b: 'b'}))
const ab = abAction('ab')
```

I would like `ab` to contain `a` and `b` properties, but `ab` returns `{}` type, that is why `ab.a` or `ab.b` are not working.

```
ab.a //err
ab.b //err
```

How can I define a type of ab that contains both 'a' and 'b' properties?

Comment: I think you meant `abAction ('a')` not `test('a')`

Comment: Yes, You are right. Sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell typescript what the return type of `reduce` will be, typescript will not be able to infer the type.

The return type should be an intersection of all the function return types. We can get a union of the function types using a type query (`AT[number]`) and we can get the return type using the `ReturnType` conditional type. To transform the union of return types to an intersection we can use the `UnionToIntersection` type from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) (don't forget to upvote jcalz)

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
(U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never
export type MakeActionType = (name: string) => { [key: string]: string }
const combineActionType = <AT extends (MakeActionType | undefined)[]>(...actionTypeList: AT) => (name: string)  => {
    return actionTypeList.reduce(
        (previous, makeActionType) => {
            const actionType = makeActionType ? makeActionType(name) : {}
            return {
                ...previous,
                ...actionType,
            }
        },
        {} 
    )  as UnionToIntersection<ReturnType<Exclude<AT[number], undefined>>>
}


const abAction = combineActionType((name) => ({a: 'a'}), (name) => ({b: 'b'}))
const ab = abAction ('a') // { a: string } & { b: string }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20UnionToIntersection%3CU%3E%20%3D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(U%20extends%20any%20%3F%20(k%3A%20U)%3D%3Evoid%20%3A%20never)%20extends%20((k%3A%20infer%20I)%3D%3Evoid)%20%3F%20I%20%3A%20never%0D%0Aexport%20type%20MakeActionType%20%3D%20(name%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20combineActionType%20%3D%20%3CAT%20extends%20(MakeActionType%20%7C%20undefined)%5B%5D%3E(...actionTypeList%3A%20AT)%20%3D%3E%20(name%3A%20string)%20%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20actionTypeList.reduce(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(previous%2C%20makeActionType)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20actionType%20%3D%20makeActionType%20%3F%20makeActionType(name)%20%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...previous%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...actionType%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20as%20UnionToIntersection%3CReturnType%3CExclude%3CAT%5Bnumber%5D%2C%20undefined%3E%3E%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20abAction%20%3D%20combineActionType((name)%20%3D%3E%20(%7Ba%3A%20'a'%7D)%2C%20(name)%20%3D%3E%20(%7Bb%3A%20'b'%7D))%0D%0Aconst%20ab%20%3D%20abAction%20('a')%0D%0Aab.a%0D%0Aab.b%0D%0A)

Comment: Thanks. One more thing `AT[number]>` is error because AT type contains MakeActionType | undefined. Could you help me resolve it?

Comment: @LeTom fixed, forgot to enable strict null checks in the playground

Comment: This will cause `previous` type cannot spread.`[ts] Spread types may only be created from object types.`

Comment: I got it, I'm so appreciate that